# Overwrite angular material css -- Why does !important work

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I'm trying to overwrite the css of some angular material components. I read about /deep/ and :ng-deep no longer being used and so I was trying to add some code in styles.css. The only thing I'm able to do is add new properties to the class, not overwrite the ones that are already there.

[image: background-color changed ok]

[image: padding didn't change at all]

Can you help me to overwrite this css?

---Update---
So I managed to change the padding using !important:

[image: Use of !important to change padding]

I would like to know if there is a better way of doing this and also why does it work?

Comment: yes I thinkg you need to use `:ng-deep` or something like that, you may also need to consider specificity and importance. If you could provide a workable demo (like on stackblitz) I would be more than happy to see if I can help you out in your specific issue

Comment: Thank you for your reply. A workable demo is a great idea, I managed to change the padding now using !important. I was wondering if it's ok to use this.

Comment: do it inside style.css you cant do inside component.css

Comment: Yes, I only changed the style.css

Comment: I think workable demos are a bit of a pain to set, but I almost always ask for them on stackoverflow as I need to play a bit with the code to be able to manage to help :P

yes your use of `!important` does not surprise me, but that is a very very very bad pattern, you should avoid that as much as you can, just use it as a last resort, only if the specificity doesn't help you

Comment: ah ok, so if you make the changes in style.css that should not force you do use and deep operators, so just going with specificity and importance should be enough, as I told you try to avoid relying on the importance if you can help it. Are you familiar with the concept of specificity?

Comment: Yes, I am :) That's what I was thinking when using !important. But I don't get why I need to use it to be honest. I though styles.css would be more specific and so it would overwrite naturally.

Comment: ah ok perfect :), styles.css doesn't impact the specificity, the only difference is that it is not bound by angular's view encapsulation so the css you put there works as standard css so you have freedom to change css which does not belong to you :)

Comment: Oh I see. Thank you Dario! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MDN Web Docs has a great explanation of CSS specificity and the role of !important in overriding the cascade. Keep in mind that id="" is more specific than class="".

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

From the docs:

> Some rules of thumb:
>
> Always look for a way to use specificity before even considering !important

> Only use !important on page-specific CSS that overrides foreign CSS

> Never use !important on site-wide CSS.

> Instead of using !important, consider:

> Make better use of the CSS cascade, Use more specific rules.

> Indicate one or more elements before the element you're selecting,
> the rule becomes more specific and gets higher priority.

IMHO your use of !important here is valid as you are overriding "external" css.

As for styling Angular Material Components, when you set up your project you are using either a pre-built or custom theme. If you have lots of customizations to make, a custom theme is the way to go.

[Angular Material Theming](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming)